# Decoding Viewstate of asp page

Tags: asp.net, decryption, viewstate

I already searched for an answer, and saw that the view state should be base64 encoded. However I used fiddler to try and decode it and the answer I get back is a string of strange characters. Here is the original url encoded viewstate portion of the request body:

```
__VIEWSTATE=gyfBu8N6DkaqZxP9jGQPbwP9L%2FSAWvjX8ej7S97c%2Fhv7SdWDBXlvtw1xyxRKctzocz3Ozk4HEuiWabj1lLiZOlzmsdwvZhWhTaNk3hwfMZdQ5k6rqLi8ZgHyaL8UmTDB6943579640CuqtVQtDgRMLa0LIrIcOqP7ulEo%2BKBYUL0XT0ticrNNKBVfKyPnoMTrFLMoCcHtfhk%2FYGPRh6%2FcYfYVmJCYq19JRR3jmEjrjtNzbC2MkXXeEAtiEy0SB69hQdC6ma5LY4Ym57g1dXA7Vq%2F8MCQUQnjCBkV%2FBiR73sMy%2FOqu%2Bi0tZFvcOI7SSj3fvCk06%2BnPGbgpR6NjyPT8SmdQFhql96wEZytSl%2BgMx%2FhsKnSoVaEs982GZsdl2rwnH4psBSncaadsZfvWxzzkNP1cxkFZNm8%2BGaFp72ewjzCKWH9qSigSd2NFGK5oy0vmrR7X7ujdzRyupza%2Fqeztu0THDK1Ss3J4KVK47p1H7WXDwp2fBR3RZlZvI95R3f4KyvpkZZ9CezFOS6wENhABvAafqm9ptiDI8EgWQFnBLK0v%2B97ul1MRm%2Fxrvu0TXmlJuFI968mg5E2VOJzZYhfyZIIGQ6RZD8m9ODmeT%2Bd6sAprucmGbE7jnh7JkixvIPkO%2BH8worYTOpXjE46R%2F0EwOE7LPBr%2BAxpRZSDe55OJZjwufb93KzeZTOQfLCM9P%2FnLyoj%2BRKgjfV4sSj0LLRG66cZWASmTgmXa6zXf3lvw%2FB7631KFgePDzjXI%2F9qD0dxLfZF8cZpTaOczSuA0l5M6uwFff%2Fg2lygRiVftYKFkOpQBHksUytm4fnowumYBBTa2WyO80KtvTnXTQevqmrFdH1mboKH5Yi1fZMsGWlH%2FONLGgCU7WPGMyWgisuHoQt7%2B6Jf55d%2Bg9uLHhtg%2B81wwFQF2kBg0zZySMFxxmuWL%2BATCnHZ2FKF07oNM19KPX7oSkYazHzwR%2B9F2RaxSop3wIDBdX1o%2FqDhpDH3dAxlpGPt%2Fx0DMyIib%2F%2FvdDwMdFT8HlS2Q9dEMyLJpRcwugR3%2BhGORZbQ2qtCXLRZdoiTrZcdqSHPU7KNURbn5DWwOhFsSM4CecpiePi7l0A%2Bukxe6NziZnbZV1Sp9nxxFRkAap72nMN5WwnuOWq6A3Rv0XYAZrBMW2w1N2TxxzWg3uV125afX2EiVHfl4P8Djc%2FPqwQamkdidSwmdLtQsd7Abt4bdd7JCHJrweeb1DBqHixCTOGzyfHsp1l%2F%2FiVOepp99IlRxAdNOjSvaaD8Gi6KsUTOkquvhpeA6umG0qvmqFUq5%2BaP75A63E0y8pdKbt1DLk9EMcEuIvpfUrZV9plj1T2b%2FWunprWJIK7nK7AJdFX12CSETMkogNjBurhGXX9jk%2FcFcFZd%2BEvfmyPj%2BMU7PkPMu5VMpIAtTJu1PYxaEj97ZuHSyd6gcw5v%2FYVYgNGGp9jPDotWLHiNZq6Vbiv6LWPi2K2BAQDrlXaRPAcJglrTy3LWm7WT6L34zILqu1WJ4YXpX3Gw86ApGQzuyEw8QioCgAen5ovKK51laQxcpFCBnrtes0BAZ4V7UF8btvZ6gsWKQ%2ByL3BkQaJZBxiEGhayEesiaMfJ4TArMxUOQrrR5EQV6JEwfORaHkp9B08aI9GJN97LsrTHN94fhc9mxqE2vjyq4%2FZF%2BxEsOGIHMkjgvFywYpeKxiIiMPc168gir23QQ5me576%2FDFaNnu7Co53pphYsg0zCgLTdBzinj5OeXhjHiMqEnGryE4SSZga7VHhLJqOLygqNm%2FZS9tMr1kcDfBW77jZx8acqvzYxyTdKmampk4eAN6%2B1zLQE5TizCcx1Ptrmzw0mkiY9R6KBd%2F6IUiqt1YtGglAZxQgRMifYt41VdZyD9D8T%2F6ScCJ%2BlWnGfoeOysOctNymnsvfzrBn750n4b%2FjJHH5%2FY5gVNRZqDd4%2BH6ZJx%2F1IusfLHLzB9SKiVjG4zCqa1lfQxz5oHhxwOVBbOt1mSNrirtqjO9ENsMA3eAi2pAnbrCYS4e5CzMx%2B6Yeb5q0MNrDtVwn3mFiRyk7bo8oryCfzGO394pz4nMQG7t%2BVj8XiO6JOn7UXLXVyiXghzcxl9njNBIN3u%2F%2FxKcFX2vak8eWrO1MZHnN1jCuy1CY8wOhwqor4qjh2x0Lit89CWgznhlOpfihx1WFgsUD14li6DwVsdHQdmOiz3r0zGlcfYb5Mej9DhZYbjVhnxDHYXA35aPRjtv71eaJjn6F9B9i2%2Br9QxhhiCfstMTkxW5RA4XDuBi7eFuGg%2Fmimc%2FSXMEFxzQFslM7moH%2FpU0opy0issGeGp19gSJ79Jfb3hfmFr%2BGr4sVA%2Fb8Xo9FLRESrfN80cX0IPex8jj%2B0oCIPZmAlHbtJjSkdL0KiQY%2FJOFpI5XEaL1SRBlBZb1zYUosOU4s7uegaoFV48rVkjNTEueJ3ohhmXWjnHanGadUv7h8GtBWeeJvzRp1BJwJt0w5Z9dIqvIJD84GAYn3gSw%2B1mDvhcw%2FM7BT7rIKK9jsIe0I6djvWCan0U96BG0K5ymD7MEJxBpmnRgDSbw%2F93giH9mK0DqbbSGy%2FpYvn805j7%2BR1EzCkKL%2FFKa6bE8DFQIG832w%2BZweOWFzQ0AGkb0hITyOZT4361z2tAja4J36vG9WotXvUwCktFQqETT2uJbcT%2Fl9%2FoEyeHJpLLLLl%2FdAhxCJMhal%2FTB2zR%2Feh2%2BvT5pmuvxUpa1nM%2BCQVyK2pTqGvUoaBZksTnEucwkG%2FH8aC5UNc7kW1kw02IFj18FUHpzmsEtgOt40SzPKU2X%2BYQpl2xu%2BJQtTiM3rqNFDU0pZsfx0c4gK%2BRV%2BmeRBGIA%2BYtm1QCczRDZlSnCvqD2ZL68EEQpRzjvtrtuba2LQ9UEcwG%2BNxHwMMjIlxfm4cLTWb1eyu8Wj4%2BzvI2Uf5L818oX9Krmxh8LmBiBX7xJx8GL40FbHG%2FAqjX4ESDOc2p956jOnZblyOCx9yd5SAB8snBoSlwSAVYacGtsApTgeodNXz5athHqiWATWLKfKZzwSIEjsELoiDaWVPQWYi3JkE6AhTNjAp7t76xn%2Bv4fFZTfMwtNyraWC%2BHvJFzSlJ9Jr2uT9i3mWw7UrPtUC5GeU5iwRKcV8dOZ7xVnci8VlhqaCYzUfvioQiHcFFxT8skL2PBEc3%2BhrispKnXQhkiPQu7bVlUwLeKIvSouhtqQ6hiHjOAOzBvaF0c19nzwJnFg3cbyluYF1vxLKyUjj%2F%2B%2BqWemhZjqHNqet1FGDBC6pKTcWJESayhWIOSHg5JDPCI9GuUcnz77sD0g92TTNkll1vSA8S0R%2FDC6wbkcf8bVF9MbgTICon3TNtDXdqAR2DXOJZ7a9t8Q%2Bi8j1v8U2W6mBnKza076KTQbG9A3jfit%2BPo2l34pv42z6%2F08jPR2e8seNQCCyDiO0TOb2TYWyTKNTrJXgl9p95h%2F6fYop3%2Fx7MwhCl5i%2FRK1cpTFjHWLxkChuIinMDzO9Ex6EvHsTJIBcsAPoWs7lo4LhMt3IR71k3OMfhYOaQxqq3Em0fRU9OwD0gRJFAU8rjTVZFrXd1i9J0AOp10m60o2KRtTlEGN2d4FYFH7DVW9lvyrgl78EPp98OJO3fSYHExtyvxWu0UNEDrt2jDgpxS6tZnWqXcMBlyvldBSFdiFl9FZD9EKtKs0F9zF0E5bnPglOU74i9YhzA7I86YlM2iW7%2BSuL%2F8DFr4jmVzeFQPsVeJafQmYGJZETi94QWWbPr359fk5yGoIfjx8JaEI4Sg0dfKKVjj4EldMMLI3ZDihiEY2zbEKGtQXHMLsU4HQ3Avowx03zxhrWneiokExHF6xjqTRVCp2%2BIsnNU6WeG15YJEhZab6Pw1kGh9rQ4Ll1sY2z0joC%2BDVwymf5CPaJkDowp%2BemMD1TXhBPJxVOy6bQoUzNmhqRp3sbtVht7vWBQB07c19HZxQQxu94yh%2FHCWB8rMd9kw0gYr3F46WLQmXPgQWtXydXau2MP%2FEu%2Fr9INd26R23Xd8l19tyl9VOxr9sQazqCORVDQW0FLrvPg%2FYNThHlNmND%2FMgmX6ogVU3LElrWHceGZUNgfVTLq46%2Bn0OYctfMwm8BT2OTca5jSZs%2BXPJ3pCMAFdFc0D96z94KTGqRlrYT0T31kNCbkvVO800TE9tUAvXjn1SwI%2BKxUXCUwV0PwhiOqcQRgvNvcIpnSASbSXL8IS7%2FMq2cNOAxqmkjtTJc%2FhYau%2Fciwq8dN2hIJeyz04jqR%2BihTHoV0QR3XcaXdJ1vbP68N1QKimJ6lldWaBQRaIQBdeu4ILLxmdlddtKCmSarhut%2FhQBNOz1PLHBmxKEB5yB1Jes8GPe%2BhjNSI2iQN2TXqFrzpYAYlHWFmBI29LK5Of7me7Bz4Ia4iRjmD9eo9phuQasWbPY4bJDivr%2BR6HJ3EgGX1m%2B4yrOfgzDrD04jSEmOXo9OYQ8qMqZSzyoUOBZ%2BMZL9vU53Ya352h3GncfNv9ayAaVLPd0C2Mx33yIedu6Sbh%2Bmouvlja9EnI9BPqERrtInFFyj4DUmZiXm4bv2ejMqaexgrXNUjYk84LFQrH3t0wenqy1q%2BOaeZ3IlqEvJz%2Ftdsaa1CKSR%2BMvtHrWVCBfW%2B8%2BLselR%2BGTqZUffQD1EzpRNhGqBynoP9%2FRMp6tnqT3UcgUzgChASA8GMyC8770BGoNlVz%2BFgsGduVBr%2FKionjyHFfF1nxkuEoUM7j7%2FTysE1BgcnaKG2YMuS8340KfxXy6jmrz7J5is9kgw2QD1nphiPZ4MsQaLNdX7Tpe%2BiaFknXItpAeRbwMrYFZWJ6DUbmW3sYhE1EvWsptOJ4G%2F9cxkz%2B6E74io0nQhBFgo78F1ajrpL2XXo2VQileH0T5T8fKt67uiYwUMXneRyj3XcPcv%2BQ4AX2LXMwOLU%2F42jQtQxKw5zaxHi5aEd421nCI7L6bHxsEvWxlSlil305y1Q0fwZe0IPN4qwiRDFtjmUDWQGtrkyBzmCupVKPkrat6r0sRnQwpBAiBSYqLBLz%2By7xl%2FeLe5MCw3cFWlsz1S3%2BlKPJvJaSpAHnA9%2B5pCpJ3LFKAXaU%2BtvBhIfj8mKrl7h8aooG2pA2n7bLdM%2FXMECUWegVf5u8p%2BJTUefxtWeipzQWdEYYQLEa1nym7sacdEpt%2BeVjJvbAtZw81Zu23bMj3OVy2cv5fWMmZbeLXgDsqFL0AkHLeJtxt9CpyBKfubqIdVV4qA59hSLa4U8kmtJjRTSTvTBLtteyp4w26BGU9htdQvJOhBqQrXHQgFr0sgiNeMgd8sTNoX0jJXdc0VdhPlOQM%2BrLr%2BicC6crNUkSvp42ipSRjdNY7PoWtd2lyaIX9N22tkH961mimnkm%2FIGtt%2BxYZ5y99AvxLXyfyiXqYz1%2BhK%2BXfABAhByn4QytVu29PWl7W29YcANoe9%2B8e6u01Je0jFVmNhHHsqMRos73QS86MA%2BGwHPTRvUDQ6hr8GtvUjX5lNyWLeWBP8ySRr%2FfdWh%2Bccnt0CAdywWlevwOMkboUVxKrr6BVIKT0sAz4ifxauQd8t%2FnGfaoMT7Rb79IDBktot8sgftdENzkGQ01FfnZqXIcXe90UeZozul005XaVQQIdzCFN9ulcicbtcgT56La%2FArsF7SzilrpiwfWE74eP3%2ByxqDxcUhMlMjCUuBcDN6kvq%2BbpZr61NwmyyImQ03LLRH46MxuIu7BLSFSc8jAeE9916MxAeNfvbSKAYrfFu6ONYwZNiHOOO%2F9k7N374SUgxQvG82lYT6iqmGWMPNmce2OiroEQycZZS2v24Yi1aBQTHsPpYQWmIV%2B270u8utSaQqL2mzo8iuqM72y2B3SIuPGtagVmsCwtup%2FjIEvmGb7T730PImr9NFJkmgdvGMKcjorR6XWDZexbR%2F1mkUftENZvNyWkbk2AR4H3IabYm1iXTMyeKSddcwjkgZXu83pMkdblTKvMzq1zCcPW8BPPY1GxRWaFLJRh%2B4NPNR4moRlNKtw6JwsMgRA4x525F5iHMiPXVm9TgA%2BXglMDzDUeI7vcM%2FiyNXPhPnrbhPx%2FqXNiLCQOwGmZH2Q73ij0%2BYoQxd1EpM2HlaaeRUk3MyAXtQ9HVSuCz%2B1nqOGtJJvELxYKVEM5VT628NFltH2W7%2FW2%2FZN1E%2BpTUMbqPkPVuiUYYSNXr8rBQ1fU88YQRjqvg00jZ8JiSui20MMf3M2eLHD1%2FyLq9R04ybYSuzZUFNqyyAPCpjpIRlvu7yy6TlJcJSneRcCrYajOtO2lnGBteG9HLB1a3dZGyErOiryqNngttl2xMIyRPp92vbjUQFu2oKMKkysUpUBy3FQdnwAKL9t%2FE7%2FyW1WgawewT%2FrT0oeGFC0f9q1AvVqOtEo48WTm3%2FFH4kDrIFTuJ39PBPjrRayfzqyDOgm9Hu49MMYwEIDrHu9UCfBwIBg8LkJEvyCD8mv6FjdnlLYMPN0yciFg7htOT1fBX%2FKobcIsSbfBob1QKZ2m6PFufmhyIsve3jdSmGDbO4pmU%2FvNpQlsKWz944cirEllxqJGzqXSBSM1TGt2hFiQYlL7QXO72V%2BYL2tcBHEFI2Jkx4MjQdEIuQoRCseSjDR27Lgxil8cd7wfACf60cDL9hz9BeX3oxP%2F00hADjF8SjVxfaLP0JzjSNIQqrDHETQSHpLE2SXXXAeN6s6FoCDSjEu0ky8sRKnPQ7BdlZ285%2Bv39hLSDKx4z49iWewJ3vA5TB%2BEQ0Y7r9y2Okg76pdhW5VIIpjDnkuFHfvZec9iu5pTNl54EexiB22zkFnZP4j0Fk52DFxR%2BUwoWM5lP4PxRFNGE4S3HCcApzwqwS%2FgU3%2Fxq6uWNrjvOEZf2U4q8l1lfwmtTASQFp6n95XB%2F4FnRvEIGRAo999B7LnxcGgKwVZCD7Dvm3oCLYrM0%2BlDpGYW5Y2SCXkzkayAbeE17L7IIXN%2FMQChf1ZRa0jJ94bBaFNu9Bw4OlOrRCT8Y%2BAotd8HG8C6evBaKQWrHgxP%2BjtN9lXTPvaEzxHSPge5gUoTTEfZSz%2FTtGWPKpMAnex3PhYHEQjejdvJeCM1RuKmx1tkQxz37FHCFMfWMDGZPXO0viqZiSz2R2sr1qr%2FOWEAZjplIqKVylpwFa5if5wid%2BZWakvBPoI7N5kQz36C79snss1DRb9es6BhIJq3crEaRrXQTqlqrfTgb%2BKoU%2B4oOo596IQGmumCzlnMVNJPIdEwxNrswoTCcYQk7vejZCl60moDxQ2a2OcqaPQI1noKPMLH%2BiSzpH9L047Quy22TPQ52HQTdzeytqHVhKao0kRFt5wMOCkj40pahTWLJbA7RiUajmArVOug6lB6mxAcCzK7kU7boYNmF%2BEpq8Fc9mUOLZeZqE%2BNfGrZO63EyqcoNMfYXjlm99asA9lSLTMkkqnCLS2NBRveW5rjRO1YBXWgWGGcqGggaY%2B%2F%2FjmpT4kX3fXALL2vB2jFQZ1CxxydUYPmze5%2FKSAsSvV0U5I0hQivesBR2u7vaBx%2BnvXMtq9XkcJPbWJHpnyafMHVHd%2BezWApu8i%2FvI9DiJyFSII2dtkpzR7WDTmupHOh8IRXqqc%2FN1Ebsc1%2BOD3TBTRSg8uYnWu7G2Fl3ipQzfDYfSq9z3xm%2BDdA9K%2BnzFVVjHzSATajhG57f65MOQHfdVKwUvxCwJxb%2B%2FiyssZJg0BuSniF3re%2ByceChXaAyuParv2HLoo4Fnk8VnaAwt1pnn%2FAdE2oZbTjiW7c2LWf3Ms76KVg5NoOvrEtKAyzPr%2BN3bMa50qCqtYsXRNOgZ%2Fq8Lhg3pe4vPCnyyOoncR0hiqFb8NpeRXDtpHAUBHCLYXL2IjPvCE774k8NJkJjtCbKhZoGuJdsQCaRB%2Bf0nSVOUdAu%2Bt2mldp7s%2F1k9WaHguneSquQsFZhJvGm8%2FPslF5NP6rTaG1xFk2aLfth4M1C6fJKR%2FCHLN1u%2FHbKX7aJCJgbV7K%2F9E%2F57AtusAQdBKYkY0J76b2cNVKAylObOKL1z65U%2BAP47tdOVgK9WYl3umviHOOQuP%2Bn2Si0hN0APIjI9YfRwarCzSnt7SJnYXOrN6WBNsDVeIgAH9Jj7qlMbSB1c9sJJOAL2Hv84dbcobOZvYIt8TT3uydM4KVfPs0uVamnRE%2F%2B1l8kszlcASI7aM%2BPyHGUzU%2B2jxdpVz5LA2FRVJb8Uwjjeez6ZlkbKra6jmK74GiWZifzbFATm6hfyjnXGWAuKfH%2FVbKeLMATtIM0J5tkBQDvFQrR8T%2BZmCw36VD3OiF2ZD%2FwMqPhNlJUmQdPaa%2BqX0b8GmNCJ2BuFOHUgoKjb6yz5YcNfRXqagzD3VdlbQRJ%2BiK7uxoog7iqUpN%2BMF4JGFKeWz3FFTfZgv0Og8L1KMe1oO0drPvHtLQSulGrtv74KgMC98jjwLefY4MCKqiAHwRY%2F0pTR2E4pQJHC3JAYnMHcOQZEUbUeUADj2E0YWdZZKriducyyLJplDozcswiUYFPcA8YlCAnc4j0vMBM5hX0%2BPKMSK%2FZPxsPMH0qkmKy%2BD4fDHSXpHQ75pxupCBIQOwdaa667Y8pbrWghimYqA36Hm4qUCAj7rsm%2FHpJw7qWBklAjUnRvLJWI%2BoNJiZORKjCUa7E0URUEh44tEruXjhK45Rm6KcNMgbFStvPHMj7KjteFNIxTqP0ddxg2%2F00tKhr%2BxyAzpLjdolpKMaYyriMuuAsqShYb14x0BFa%2BNOBtGSf3BMZOEFKbaxj8xW6sTPAk2aO3e4vg%2B0llnIYc3zhjND%2BrWKXeK15Izy1WDn2XgFJ8yw%2FUGSOOgZiEUPx%2BkguEFn%2Bl7aX8o0LB0kq2C0yUMKmApj%2Fr9NjUSL%2BvXRtEN2NE66qym0eJmOi9WtS2dn1H6doZ87YYQe36DIGnT%2FLQUxPC4DBA8lo3C8cJG6C14MDS4zFPClUY6IINhjAf6OqMF3F6oMnsJCEiFjcpKBWGYFZVe4%2Bts0IVb2lcBezzmkL5qERMt3DCnYDTGlDmpikGOvxwSshMy%2FCnC69r3nPyjUsclHn1dreB6GJxEwTyTia9tjOVN99tyi2B95ywIRT3S1%2B%2BZNEJHlmwxuOwfDaMBz1LuuJZMb%2BEUG%2BZipiCA8cl03j4Klw3y0k7RR7cYgjTDa3TUJyzQb2nJd%2B9prm65kgJhcsga6SGqvCoJ6%2FAQJXfldo3dkyWcItzH8H83Agf10n1Ff0xEZFCUv3jndjDJ%2FbBEjJzZeHDGLfeJ%2BCNPnBSPY%2F2%2F3ST%2BRW3T%2Fva%2B0AkjqPuWmRz5gq27mZYv6YYN2P2HUYyzLfq7B6Wbql3HM1Hq%2B31%2Fb0w8nw9MR8AWkTTfRqVisHYHpLvO07EnhCAHizdYvr%2FzSlJbf7TDhmbCi0UHUf%2BbzmW3V1%2F5zAE64ihbyR%2FNa982vj%2FxI%2FHHVMBKnhEEfrhKMPH7oKjhQ4O%2Bh1u%2B6dq9B7PLpA2u1zs%2Fpmj9bJ%2BgKc6Gl4GlTk9mMFJfGK5yffcPwXhv5kk3Dx%2BDYxX1tMGQZSDxwK5SYy6rXnoY1JBggBNHpopQI%2BaHJTiUde14aacz1KGQ6IYeszlNX23a9wYwjnZZxqjpbC1uYJjF8YrI26vnSS1NTIXPh%2BJGyTTliwWc7dv3fxmleVKLQU7F1e5K7o%2BTsXQoUUx9tlCT7k12pHuCTovApa%2FCE47PNizvYZcNZ6LBw3Q0E4T5njGIyLNbSNQp5wIhEg6%2F9%2BRNdNteWhMbgmImlBDUdjVc2uj1Eb2criXRaxxw3ik7QA17%2B7VdQOPEiAm%2B%2F%2Ff9hFY8vGD7XPWAKApRoMeJ6y6kjnGSQCgU0TDclR1sXt%2Be8TBaMfPtR23%2BldSQAVx0aAeBjYTYtFxl4%2F%2Fxyec6KFM0S%2Bb2nU1if3Fuo%2FE8TDDTif%2FlEZ4JjBnAH8d3Vs%2Br2388R7MaRC7uCP0pTCKe8HGVLZvonevfxMptHZo2tzKs31kzkep%2BrLIXLhfUpreM5QYDl7V1cVX%2BQQz6bMLqerWkzNNBtSzlSnfSD7tvtAcVcC99rITEmKNebJEEYP0lrP%2FouGuHCyURIt46ImhtTaKgpGj2OFSbfP6hPDBWJAxjiotJ4z8J53Lh%2BDRcEXSIqbFFzB88ORyCCgjK%2BNSuwy3aSWLv66qDNLPTzE5fHqClmm2WWCAHJ0yOe1epypRnz9%2BFiu8Wyvf8mRkeIha8oOCQJza5haPgT8CMyMlEvfpxZMwWwyyDAvFcNX2whU1iP%2Fk7A1gad4KKy5YPLYwoAXE%2B9hOSPycHw%2B0r7zOot5NyoL4ZsE8IipksR6aj41dcO8Z7DFFt1BreUmzNM58vR2nvcoL0KAabENprVa43U4IJgGMm7iYZdAKX5epDyBH7TaGX37r6m%2FT6IM80Ck6nPZjiVZjUYmza6XSMF9CmKKZu8s75dPREBLr1neSiHzAcQRDIDgLS32sLam%2BYa7X6ptXe%2FWVx5p1VyigfVwtCkI9YJfoWu77cP2T15gZDMvSCS3vIU0BbgjcBGJVKWtJl%2Fca5bd9oQ6MvSL4IuvU8DtvpjJJA%2FKga%2BXUNE51gYY4kyn8YZj8upnT4iBQkBoaKiI5nggqsI0mK6MsOXVbnxpO2Bs%2BgZp45ueKHJrO7p62UtLXCOs0pI0mJIyqGUn6R2NFG1uT77rwClwZz4%2FZsV0v95dxD43E04akuyRA5VluhnoHGyOuA5hmJVhkhCDukjoIka3vXjA%2BVnKqqokvl4bnxff4IzMgw3TeR%2BhmVruqRqNy2wCs6QBwfGV2tiMzEP2A7X5xEup1g3BSrdsGiAfJ9AsNspJWFnCkszp2WVJsbmQ%2B6klj5HPb3Y94Lo%2FouUTRZJaJF7YutY%2BEPHGgGxaZ6Izq6OxgDnkc9FuGValaW9zEIBv7bkOzOeXpednDs1h9PbADQJaK4o0BzLS8ujfA5ktqSh7CRzcXkWKmN7wubOHT%2B0tRg6IgCBNMb8NPMMREoCSxvPav5P9DnWnX%2FQ6IfmP%2F1oLB6x9jx9C%2BpduHvMIKga9cx1xOD9soqLVPzy29dMWlMWsUDRv%2FD%2FVRO%2BYyRD4qHgvhyPb%2FkVGJitoDY%2BRGv55hgFJ3%2FIxwdIa4uhqVamuEXmUGHELE%2B5ZOypylpcaYT9M5occ49PR0jndT1w3HgEqrtdhVn04Yi5eq2abuLgVo58Ip5bZrCjzG%2FqoJrG8lYyW4y7hT6I5K02yZ3aI4cjKcG02IOQOxHREa%2Bqib0uvOmHzKs0mKGxizIME6ZJo0BQlFUJCk23WJGDJBD3BpnkZpOORPOB0zrwBIXgWoqSv%2Fn9Z1NGpTofPnBdFzz4M8%2FR7WjDi0I33Vp7YKIYB%2BeePpfp9ZCerFpqBlXKep%2FpwUViB43X8%2FZI8sVA1HzPt%2F%2BriquUfdMqKYmcZHI3o20GcWpO05GRRA45OJTStiL3cB7tjSTd7xt5LBASX0%2FpIVJI75yRmj1%2F2z5rNYrIgFnEy%2FJf6WbqCP14QvvmkRoePZNjHzg6eu%2B6s2ZZApGfnNu5V0Rfs4rmbdK1u9hkRVkLY5LnC%2F%2Fr1PFUcoHLqYNXn7V64%2Bm61Fd9aWDW%2B%2BcJoi7gLAiCTmCdmKyTmifW4FXWkPpxfxmZIBNcixwnZ30k1ega8o5QkUxqG%2F%2FHkKgPyfMQVbpme%2BUFZG2g9gbH6CbRK8BlapmxDemJgHe9sCfshFAqVKcbSTrWWcg7DkDpdJLoMuN0Qru8%2FEiF4zAOhZNtrTumCgDqjpyCtagmcmiApcAVzU%2BiJTgI8Isffcp%2F2RV47lOyZkuyml6VQy7EOIByVRYubFptZizPX08trRg4wUT9sDRlGtjMPOf0xRQNdrtqdthuX1DfGu2FNMFtmc9HBEdcbocnzCm67OzcCzCn%2F9caJ0TYPc7gjMij%2Bf4bZcQrcQIoojYJz%2FQYsYasGsLyB15KbH3AxyHaenaSE9B6MwsKewH%2Bmynm8M9jJlPLGRTjNpz5fu%2BRO7aOWlMY3lrPeM9R7eYX%2BZwD4cTAJEhBsPJoCty%2FNsDUpXV%2FM32JUSchFCXryXRv%2Fu9kSdS2JUvNTxD33Lg7TTyyPYby76MIVHE8PYEMjh3Sv85dx64gHZVc%2BrCH%2F%2B6Jpvg5FtFUiBKr8YFSPZGvCmFN1ZwDmXj6F8SZBGW%2FffETke7%2FXrlHTkhG3pEL%2FlFERMNQPls12IPe6wJtn9ks7rq7P%2FI%2BFjIcqkTrXm5K4NnclRlg1dli3LpF6zNHn9%2BWHtrgR9ymhDlZBTkyPc%2Fmo6yMXKAJlh007UxgFpSEsoW9S480fWZH%2FBYpRZCBAl1c6JDxhXFXeH3HEQ2HrbHiXgbD0z3ukqRLRA9bVD28LFuB5JYAHUNCTUVjWlERgSV%2FZ1V1HHkcDwSkU2pF7b8P2QAYWDpG3KrpbDQ8uetNqz6p5jiM9NADkbuAjjrB5akIQFfGvCrtybJYIv4P7CjQzqe2gqmZ4DEEQkE57rT2bBJoXjM%2FVYWC7qdaZKCRfY2jKgbwlAwX1mhmVq1OyY3acw9Yg6UjHldDeZD8RpC%2Bm2ln5PDm1xVkYVDXyOD%2BNf2Je%2FCHLe8joVHtr5K4kSpNHM9lA%2F3%2BpSPmVV7Qng5prlNhva67ThSKeg7WshVopOdamtFno4TkUj8FGWBrUBel5DtvBz4%2Bg0y%2B6PNiDgsdC9rgYKHBe7J7njJZloGkgE0x7fdj94eXffUCHNyalf8Y3gueusmlcbH2kzcVLey3PkNRVz0itZh0JSOXv8qmbUDSZKHtX9HLba9O1c4tRVRMEp%2FhcZf8Dn4lUtUpydryMDexGiFkipxQ3b%2BG3zIifIabPnkEwdKz2cv0DQdHeNh8hbDTpEmEfZoodIDniIvxizLgVUKruDbM07zpSNh0Cnc0WWEv8GVsiO2EMG9NJ8RmA1G80r%2Bz7h4lxkJTLJxtrMSx0cZgEi7D1dxzJkEqSX%2FpRM%2BQAM5o7zC83BCvj48%2Ffl1a1AcajBUKoG2FoMyn4kKuHGp%2F1CZElfEPfIEdk0D2HkwDfDo4TgMXFVOFcAulrSFsAoLQsRF0TYAqBB%2BNvPs3QBuGP0W9ViuUFQt8Pq2C464CHQXXlUm%2BaGXsssqGPNuwF25zs0K5WA3v6Az%2F089vHySlXMR1uoWODn1KJUuygQUnXOnPQKwQ7GVhPf%2F85U%2BWfF2fNoxz3rYxYaGEMmWX5VChs09U%2BdOhbdDcaQtzLkcBxUXUap%2BkLySg6Up2e5ebnKVwqmkDnPBPe%2BtpLYDbVwEkrGlm%2FGAbqp4WuR2UgxtqR2GfwVO1kH0tpJO9311JBg9EuB5qaFDclUazWYlowFUbtFxffZu7MZFmWhyYFhJMo%2FSa5A4QwjJUJ60aJ4V6G16yOtgTW2lXtpAlW3a0Sh7bypIlQ5XY2Oil09oeNEkSaVMzODldnS6TJsqmwTR4YBER6WgQDM1427UtCTEQKrwL2mvuV8VbrrIda%2F5RWf06jVujYs%2BklQHr%2FhTZBr30vIrzTINmd4gXdJ35YMBTkBYid9zyRKGoUoEKmviIgVIx8TlelIsJFL3xMZ0YFyVMJ%2B8%2B9DuDJXhL2xReKJD7RBgq5lU7%2BxC0%2BJiGrQeA%2BZjHWRPDsf6alM5q1Y9p%2F3uBF46IdPgqwmzrWwpv6IgsSyye7P8fa3PdX2JgvQvJgIKe9Nu2BVEoqVTyK8UtEu%2Ftoj2BTDWT5YgsAvbW7tEQX5SeVnilnGzu2NABCsezK0266xy4RoWGcZGJ6Xxz6tPqoGUhXa8QdrtXunML9aFfVOxA5ZbQxs%2B1Qrhx5eUATM6vSVyDq3HzOjiJKmN97VOaj9RjxJhX%2FAthb7YzkxSb4FsPCXqcqu9mPJmu3XqJxa9weaiSKDIqjvOw9hpZ9YIchjrLx4HniSjuv5CrrbmSfqy4PofEkiNOQmkJUx8hHBezoivO%2BxV91cWjzeSQMZJoCJsIceGcYtjIcUe6Zw8p91SFtbQ1sG6EaxCTJfTJl%2Bgymxzn7KdfFry5lQB2xhFuS0F%2FYkzfg%2FTageYBj29Qwv%2BDbs0CbtYvPnzBI%2BmKMZi5QM1%2BoB51A5UVoM%2FeD1bqVL4NHcQhMfDVfraxsj4F1j6jjetEVVBRxzbfIi4KuhCMHOetdhLmdsS7Mu%2Bif%2FoPfoOqUgsafzr70Wh9ZfCCyQdstal8KvrfhV2w%2FFRbkIAJp9Xy9mZ2AxhJOOQiQ1j%2FEl5lwMb47n4GdAk7HcAQprywls9AS51GH%2F27hmiHbbHPtFT6Ivenw2Jbhvi78bikR2fmVspe0EiuoQ3osiy1u5pvpLKQsoS3JHkb72j%2BEObtQ0qk7pVlkAHR%2BZ2hdjurt7b%2FwypeV9KRj9fb4GRIAOYIo%2FpGrfleTKDS1yleXpUde8Ngxu3OBIYPF5NA7ksZNVptyraxRRIUSZ%2BsUn0h77VXcgfiGD2BrGNW4V8n9hbxvUD0LzQmk5RP9qQd9C3wQ%3D%3D
```

Here is the urldecoded string:

```
 __VIEWSTATE=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
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate

Comment: I had already (I did a google search and then a stackoverflow search before coming here). It seemed like I had found the answer, but when trying to decode from base64 the data is still all jumbled (tried it online with the various tools described in that page and also with fiddler's textwizard).